# How do you derive this boundary condition?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

**The Question:**

Suppose a circular cylinder of radius $a$ moves with constant velocity $U$ in the $x$-direction in a two-dimensional irrotational, incompressible flow whose velocity decays to zero at infinity.

The circulation around the cylinder is zero.

Let $\phi$ be the velocity potential of the flow. Show that

$$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial r} = U\cos \theta \qquad \text{ on } \;\;r=a$$

where $(r,\theta)$ are the plane polar coordinates.

---

So basically, I don't really know how to put all the given information together.

How do I deduce anything about the velocity potential at $r=a$ if the cylinder moves with constant velocity?

Any hints would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For potential flow, the fluid velocity is the gradient of the potential, $\mathbf{u} = \nabla \phi$.

The boundary condition at a solid (impermeable) surface is the no flux condition. If $\mathbf{n}$ is the unit normal vector and $\mathbf{U}$ is the velocity at a point on the surface the no-flux condition is expressed as

$$\nabla \phi \cdot \mathbf{n} = \mathbf{U} \cdot \mathbf{n}$$

Using polar coordinates, the velocity of the cylinder is $U \mathbf{e}_x = U \cos\theta \,\mathbf{e}_r - U \sin \theta \, \mathbf{e}_\theta$, and the normal vector is $\mathbf{n} = \mathbf{e}_r$.

Hence, the boundary condition at the surface, where $r = a$, is

$$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial r} = \nabla \phi \cdot \mathbf{e}_r =  [U \cos\theta \,\mathbf{e}_r - U \sin \theta] \cdot \mathbf{e}_r = U \cos \theta $$